# Closed-form solution to intricate matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbf{A}(\alpha) = \big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{B}\big)^{-1}$ be the inverse of a convex combination of the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix $\mathbf{I}$ and a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix $\mathbf{B}$, where the combination is given by $\alpha \in (0, 1]$. The matrix $\mathbf{B}$ is not invertible. For some $n$-dimensional vector $\mathbf{c}$, I want to find $\alpha$ such that
$$
\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{A}(\alpha) \big( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B} \big) \mathbf{A}(\alpha) \mathbf{c} = 0.
$$

Is there a closed-form solution for $\alpha$?

(I'm aware that a solution might not always exist.)

(In case it's helpful, note that $\mathbf{B}$ can be written as $\mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{D}$ for some $m$-by-$n$ matrix $\mathbf{D}$, where $m < n$.)

Comment: The matrix $B$ is positive semidefinite but rank deficient.  For any $\alpha>0$, $\alpha I + (1-\alpha)B$ is nonsingular.  If $I-B$ is nonsingular, then there will be now solution.

Comment: Thank you @BrianBorchers for pointing this out. Indeed, I expect $\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}$ to be invertible. However, I don't quite understand why that implies that no solution exists. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: Sorry- if $I-B$ is positive definite, then there will be no solution.

Comment: Good point. But it will often not be positive definite.

Comment: In case someone wants an example, let $\mathbf{B}$ be 3-by-3 with rows $(17, 22, 27)$, $(22, 29, 36)$ and $(27, 36, 45)$. Let $\mathbf{c} = (1, 6, 2)$. Then $\alpha \approx 0.8622245$, which I derived numerically.

Comment: @FredrikSavje Really?  I get $0.8789278759$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You're right. I must have copied the wrong number. Here's a Julia snippet showing that Robert got the right $\alpha$: `a = 0.8789278759; c = [1, 6, 2]; D = [1:3 4:6]; B = D * D'; A = inv(a * I + (1-a) * B); c' * A * (I - B) * A * c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\mathbf{B}$ is positive semidefinite symmetric matrix so we can write $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}$ where $\mathbf{P}$ is a orthogonal matrix ($\mathbf{P}^{-1} =\mathbf{P}^T$) and $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix ($d_i > 0$ for all $i=1,...,n$). We have
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}(\alpha) &= \big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{B}\big)^{-1} \\
&= \big(\alpha  \mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{P} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}\big)^{-1} \\
&= \big(\mathbf{P}^{-1}\big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{D}\big)\mathbf{P}\big)^{-1} \\
&= \mathbf{P}^{-1}\big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{D}\big)^{-1}\mathbf{P} \\
\end{align}

Hence
\begin{align}
\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{A}(\alpha) \big( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B} \big) \mathbf{A}(\alpha) \mathbf{c} &= \mathbf{c}^T \left(\mathbf{P}^{-1}\big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{D}\big)^{-1} \mathbf{P} \right) (\mathbf{P}^{-1}(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{D})\mathbf{P})  \left(\mathbf{P}^{-1}\big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{D}\big)^{-1} \mathbf{P} \right)\mathbf{c} \\
&= (\mathbf{P}\mathbf{c})^T \big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{D}\big)^{-1}  (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{D}) \big(\alpha \mathbf{I} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{D}\big)^{-1} (\mathbf{P}\mathbf{c}) \\
&=(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{c})^T \mathbf{Q} (\mathbf{P}\mathbf{c})\\
&=\mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{e}
\end{align}

where $ \mathbf{Q}$ is a diagonal matrix with the values

$$q_{i} = \frac{1-d_i}{\big(\alpha+(1-\alpha)d_i\big)^2} \qquad \forall i=1,...,n$$

$\qquad$ and $\mathbf{e}$ is a vector defined by $\mathbf{e} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{c}$

Then
$$\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{A}(\alpha) \big( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B} \big) \mathbf{A}(\alpha) \mathbf{c}  = 0 \iff \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{Q}(\alpha) \mathbf{e} =0 \iff \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{(1-d_i)e_i^2}{\big(\alpha+(1-\alpha)d_i\big)^2}  = 0$$
$\qquad$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{(1-d_i)e_i^2}{\big((1-d_i)\alpha+d_i\big)^2}  = 0 \tag{1}$$

The equation $(1)$ has real solution if and only if $\{(1-d_i)\}_{i=1,...,n}$ don't have the same sign ($\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{B}$ is *not* positive definite or negative definite), in other words, there exists $k$ such that $$1<k<n$$ $\qquad$ and $$0<d_1\le d_2 \le ... \le d_k < 1 < d_{k+1} \le ...\le d_n$$

If this condition is satisfied, the equation $(1)$ can be solved easily with a numerical method but there is no closed-form solution for $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you @NN2 this is incredibly helpful. Showing that it's tied to the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$ is exactly the type of condition I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The left side of your equation is a rational function of $\alpha$.  The roots of its numerator are "closed form" according to some definitions,
although if it has degree $5$ or more they may not be expressible in radicals.

In the $3 \times 3$ example in the comment, the equation is
$$ \frac{17424 \alpha^{4}+14688 \alpha^{3}-49128 \alpha^{2}-24786 \alpha +39366}{\alpha^{2} \left(36 \alpha^{2}+17 \alpha -54\right)^{2}}$$

The numerator is an irreducible quartic, and the expression in radicals for its roots is not pretty.

Comment: Thanks! I meant "closed form" in the informal sense of "nice, interpretable expression", so it seems I'm out of luck on that.